# Passing information up the stack in an Exception?

Tags: python, exception

I am getting an exception deep in some loop in a function in a long running process.  If I get an exception, I would like to log a thing that is at the index in the loop at which the exception occurred.  Unfortunately, the information that I need isn't available in the current function... it's in the next function up the stack.  However, the index isn't available in the next function up the stack, it is only available in the current function. In order to log the appropriate info, I therefore need information from two function calls at different nesting levels.  How do I pass information between functions in an `Exception`?

For example:

```
def foo():
    information_I_need = ["some", "arbitrary", "things"]
    data_operated_on = list(range(0, 10*len(information_I_need), 10)) #0,10,20
    #NB: these two lists are the same size
    try:
        bar(data_operated_on)
    except ValueError as e:
        i = e.get_the_index_where_bar_failed()
        print(information_I_need[i])

def bar(aoi):
    for i in range(len(aoi)):
        try:
            fails_on_10(aoi[i])
        except ValueError as e:
            e.add_the_index_where_bar_failed(i)
            raise e

def fails_on_10(n):
    if n == 10:
        raise ValueError("10 is the worst!")
```

The expected behavior here would be that a call to `foo()` prints `"arbitrary"`.

In this example, `bar` has information (namely, the index `i`) that `foo` needs to correctly report the problem.  How do I get that information from `bar` up to `foo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the index as an attribute of the exception object.

It's best to do this with a custom exception class, rather than using one of the built-in exceptions.

```
class BadInformation(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, index):
        # py2/3 compat
        # if only targeting py3 you can just use super().__init__(message)
        super(BadInformation, self).__init__(message)
        self.bad_index = index

def foo():
    information_I_need = ["some", "arbitrary", "things"]
    data_operated_on = list(range(0, 10*len(information_I_need), 10)) #0,10,20
    #NB: these two lists are the same size
    try:
        bar(data_operated_on)
    except BadInformation as e:
        i = e.bad_index
        print(information_I_need[i])

def bar(aoi):
    # if you need both the index and value, use `enumerate()`
    for index, value in enumerate(aoi):
        try:
            fails_on_10(value)
        except ValueError as e:
            raise BadInformation(str(e), index)
            ## on py 3 you may want this instead
            ## to keep the full traceback
            # raise BadInformation(str(e), index) from e



def fails_on_10(n):
    if n == 10:
        raise ValueError("10 is the worst!")
```

Comment: While technically legal, adding unexpected attributes to a builtin exception is not a good idea - for example, you might get a totally unrelated `ValueError` which won't have this attribute.  You want to either use a custom dedicated exception class or at least handle the case where the exception doesn't have the additional attribute (`getattr()` is your friend here).   Also, you probably want to use `raise from` (python3) or (if you're using python 2 and insist on dynamically adding an attribute) use a bare `raise`, so you don't lose the traceback.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm not so familiar with all the details, so feel free to write an answer that shows how to do it correctly.

Comment: all you need to improve your answer (which is mostly correct) is in my comment, so you could at the same time learn more about "the details" and get rep points here (be sure I'll upvote your answer if you improve it).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks, take a look at my `BadInformation` exception.

Comment: I allowed myself to add a couple last improvements - and you get my upvote ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: You got the `super` call wrong - you need to pass the current class, not the parent class, as the first argument. I'm not sure whether to include `index` in the superclass constructor call - it doesn't raise an error, but there are arguments for and against it.

Comment: @user2357112 omg! Thanks for the fix (me go get another coffee) ;-)

Comment: @user2357112 wrt/ passing the second argument to the `super()` call, it makes it available in `e.args`, which can be useful in some cases.